# Drupal picture module uninstall

Tags: image, drupal, module, uninstallation

I cannot uninstall the drupal picture module.

I disabled the module at Admin > Modules
Went to Admin > Modules > Uninstall. I ticked the checkbox and try to uninstall.

I am getting that error when trying to unistall it.

Fatal error: Call to undefined function file_type_load_all() in /www/htdocs/liyago.com/sites/all/modules/picture/picture.install on line 91

Is there any other way to unistall it.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to apply patch #4 from the corresponding issue: https://www.drupal.org/node/2604628 and then uninstall the module.